# scanning a string ,( which produces diverent values in release and debug mode)

Tags: c++, debugging, release

```
sscanf(path.data(),"%*[D:/Resize/Resize/ScaledImages2/CamLeft_]%s", &cam_value);
```

during debug mode `cam_value = 36340000.tiff;` 
while during relese mode `cam_value = 0593634000.tiff;` ( this is true value to be parsed)
why the string is parsed differently in different mode?

Answer (score 1):

That format specification will not read anything into the variable.

```
sscanf(path.data(),"%*[D:/Resize/Resize/ScaledImages2/CamLeft_]%s", &cam_value);
//                   ^^ The * indicates ignore the data. Don't read into any variable.
```

Comment: but I see the same sipnnet working correct in release mode( i want to get the cam_value from the string path.data(), not to check the content of cam_value, because it keeps on changing for different files)

Comment: @GurucharanSrinivas, my initial response was not correct.

Comment: What is the string being returned by path.data()?  Are you sure that's not being affected by the different build options?

Comment: path.data() returns a string "D:/Resize/Resize/ScaledImages2/CamLeft_05936340000.tiff".  now the &cam_value gets string "36340000.tiff" in debug mode and in release mode it gets "05936340000.tiff" , you can see in debug mode its not taking first 3 digits of the number.

Comment: @P.Hinker what do you mean by not affected by the different build?, I think it is not affected.